# Different default persist for RDD and Dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I was trying to find a good answer for why the default persist for RDD is `MEMORY_ONLY` whereas for Dataset it is `MEMORY_AND_DISK`. But I couldn't find it.

Does anyone know why the default persistence levels are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For rdd the default storage level for persist api is MEMORY and for dataset is MEMORY_AND_DISK

Please check the below

[SPARK-3824][SQL] Sets in-memory table default storage level to MEMORY_AND_DISK

As mentioned by @user6910411 "**Spark SQL currently uses MEMORY_ONLY as the default format. Due to the use of column buffers however, there is a huge cost to having to recompute blocks, much more so than Spark core.**" i.e dataset/dataframe apis use column buffers to store the column datattype and column details about the raw data so in case while caching the data does not fit in to memory then it will not cache the rest of the partition and will recompute whenever needed.So in the case of dataset/dataframe the recomputation cost is more compared to rdd due to its columnar structure.So the default persist option changed to MEMORY_AND_DISK so that the blocks that does not fit in to memory will spill to disk and it will retrieved from disk whenever needed rather than recomputing next time.

Answer (score 6):

Simply because `MEMORY_ONLY` is rarely useful - it is not that common in practice to have enough memory to store all required data, so you're often have to evict some of the blocks or cache data only partially.

Compared to that `DISK_AND_MEMORY` evicts data to disk, so no cached block is lost.

The exact reason behind choosing `MEMORY_AND_DISK` as a default caching mode is explained by, [SPARK-3824](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3824) (*Spark SQL should cache in `MEMORY_AND_DISK` by default*):

> Spark SQL currently uses MEMORY_ONLY as the default format. Due to the use of column buffers however, there is a huge cost to having to recompute blocks, much more so than Spark core. Especially since now we are more conservative about caching blocks and sometimes won't cache blocks we think might exceed memory, it seems good to keep persisted blocks on disk by default.