# Should cache and checkpoint be used together on DataSets? If so, how does this work under the hood?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am working on a Spark ML pipeline where we get OOM Errors on larger data sets. Before training we were using `cache()`; I swapped this out for `checkpoint()` and our memory requirements went down significantly. However, in the docs for `RDD`'s `checkpoint()` it says:

> It is strongly recommended that this RDD is persisted in memory, otherwise saving it on a file will require recomputation.

The same guidance is not given for `DataSet`'s checkpoint, which is what I am using. Following the above advice anyways, I found that the memory requirements actually increased slightly from using `cache()` alone.

My expectation was that when we do

```
...
ds.cache()
ds.checkpoint()
...
```

the call to checkpoint forces evaluation of the `DataSet`, which is cached at the same time before being checkpointed. Afterwards, any reference to `ds` would reference the cached partitions, and if more memory is required and the partitions are evacuated that the checkpointed partitions will be used rather than re-evaluating them. Is this true, or does something different happen under the hood? Ideally I'd like to keep the DataSet in memory if possible, but it seems there is no benefit whatsoever from a memory standpoint to using the cache and checkpoint approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** You won't benefit from in-memory cache ([default storage level for `Dataset` is `MEMORY_AND_DISK` anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130402/10958683)) in subsequent actions, but you should still consider caching, if computing `ds` is expensive.

**Explanation**

Your expectation that

> ```
> ds.cache()
> ds.checkpoint()
> ...
> ```
>
> the call to checkpoint forces evaluation of the DataSet

is correct. `Dataset.checkpoint` comes in different flavors, which allow for both eager and lazy checkpointing, and [the default variant is eager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L561)

```
def checkpoint(): Dataset[T] = checkpoint(eager = true, reliableCheckpoint = true)
```

Therefore *subsequent* actions should reuse checkpoint files.

However, under the covers Spark simply [applies `checkpoint` on the internal `RDD`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L614), so the rules of evaluation didn't change. Spark evaluates action first, and then creates `checkpoint` (that's why caching was recommended in the first place).

So if you omit `ds.cache()` `ds` will be evaluated twice in `ds.checkpoint()`:

- Once for [internal `count`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L622).
- Once for actual `checkpoint`.

Therefore nothing changed and `cache` is still recommended, although recommendation might might slightly weaker, compared to plain `RDD`, as `Dataset` cache is considered computationally expensive, and depending on the context, it might be cheaper to simply reload the data (note that `Dataset.count` without `cache` is normally optimized, while `Dataset.count` with `cache` is not - [Any performance issues forcing eager evaluation using count in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50379782/10958683)).

Comment: In "Dataset.count without cache is normally optimized, while Dataset.count without it, is not" -> the last should be **"with it"** and not **"without it"** right ?